# R+LaTeX: font metrics unknown for Unicode character U+043c

Tags: r, latex

There was a problem with the name of the graph axes. Necessary to use in the axis   name Cyrillic, xample **ум.одн** (the code below).

```
<<echo=FALSE,size='normalsize',fig.width=5, fig.height=4,results = "asis">>=
result <- read.table(file='results/mydata',sep = ";",nrows = 5,header =TRUE)
p <- ggplot(data = result, aes(y = n, x=r)) +
geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, color="orange", formula = y ~ x) +
stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ x, 
          aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), 
          parse = TRUE) +         
geom_point() + xlab( expression('r'^-1~'м'))+ ylab( expression('n'~'ум.одн'))
p
```

After compilation I get an error:

```
## Warning in grid.Call(L_stringMetric,
as.graphicsAnnot(x$label)): font metrics unknown for
Unicode character U+043c
```

What is the problem?